# List of registry identifiers for MSI deployment

Tags: .net, registry, setup-deployment

One is [TargetDir]. There have to be more. Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following msdn link has a list of the Windows Installer properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(v=VS.85).aspx

Good luck.